# How to invoke a process in remote agent via Bamboo server

Tags: java, continuous-integration, bamboo, continuous-deployment

We are having a test automation tool which is written in java, we want to invoke this test automation tool (installed on remote agent) from Bamboo server, It will return some response and bamboo build will PASS/FAIL on the basis of response returned by the tool.
Any suggestions/links/comments will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Script task, which will execute this tool at agent side. If you have several remote agents, then you need to add Capability to your agent and add the same capability to requirements of build. In such configuration plan will be executed only at valid remote agent